# Shortcode with no attribute but has value

Tags: shortcode

I'm almost finished the re-skin and development of a customer site, and one of the final items I need to build support for is the audio shortcode they're using. The problem I'm having is that the audio shortcode does not use an attribute, but has an attribute value:

```
[audio=http://1234.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/audiofile.mp3]
```

How do I render this on the page?

I would use the following function, but there is no attribute in the above shortcode:

```
function audio_shortcode($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'uri' => ''
    ), $atts);

    return '<audio controls><source src="' . $a['uri'] . '" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
}
add_shortcode('mp3audio', 'audio_shortcode');
```

I reviewed the documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API but it doesn't have any examples here `[scode="value"]`.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39027/use-shortcode-value-instead-of-shortcode-att-value?rq=1

Comment: Thank you cjbj. It did help. Unfortunate there wasn't more information about this use case anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

When no attribute is used but a value is provided, the value is added to `$atts[0]`. Using `$atts[0]`, I'm now able to get the value output doing the following:

```
function audio_shortcode($atts) {
    if($atts[0] != '') {
        return '
            <div class="audiofile">
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="' . $atts[0] . '" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            </div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('audio', 'audio_shortcode');
```